# How to discover another device without using Gamekit, EAaccessory and core Bluetooth framework in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth

I want to detect the device without using `GameKit framework`, `EAaccessory` framework & `core Bluetooth` framework. Since the device which i want to discover doesn't have BLE.

Can it possible in iOS ?

Comment: ok, then what your device is capable of?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to be in control of your device, otherwise there is no way.

If you're controlling your other device, you can setup Bonjour on it. Beware this is not an easy walk - neither on the device's side nor on the iOS side.

The Apple docs (https://developer.apple.com/bonjour) don't help too much, but https://github.com/tolo/HHServices might help you get started with the iOS side. (It's designed for iOS to iOS over Bluetooth, but the code should also work with WiFi with minor modifications. It will not work with Non-MFI Bluetooth devices.) For the device side, you might want to have a look at http://jmdns.sourceforge.net.